# Form field added dynamically with jQuery doesn't submit to server

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I am using jQuery's append() to add an indeterminate amount of hidden form fields to my form. When I add one, the code looks like this:

the jQuery is:

```
var teamName = "Dansk";
var newTeam = "<input type="hidden" name="tag" value="' + teamName + '">";
$('#team-display').append(newTeam);
```

the HTML is like this after runing this:

```
<div id="team-display">

</div>
```

So here is thing: If I run this, and I inspect the DOM using Chrome's inspector, the code looks perfect, the correct info goes into the HTML, it look like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="tag" value="Dansk">
```

but the script that it passes to just runs **phpinfo()** which echoes back the POST variables passed to form, and it does not show up, **however** the thing is, if I copy and paste that exact form field into the page in the exact right space WITHOUT adding it via jQuery, it does POST. So I know I'm sticking it in the right spot.

Comment: are you using raw languages or any type of framework? A framework may well be stopping form tampering, which basically means any sneaky browser user fiddling with a form by adding hidden fields etc. is stopped :-) This is actually pretty important and well worth knowing about, as if you're doing this sort of thing with javascript then you'll hit this problem in the future for sure (if it isn't the source of this problem)

Comment: does your html have a `<form>.....</form>` container?

Comment: yes it does have a form container. The only other thingI'm using is Pure.css responsive grid thing and it has no javbascript

Comment: Maybe you need to add the new input into the form container? Because the form submit button is associated with a form...

Comment: Paul, I don't quite follow you, how do you mean to add it to the form container? I am sticking it in between the form and /form tags, but maybe you mean another thing?

Comment: @Cocorico do you actually have errors in your definition of `newTeam`?  Look at your single and double quotes.  If `team-display` div is inside the form that you're trying to POST, then this should work, besides the malformed `<input>` tag defined by `newTeam`.

Comment: @EricLease no, I am pretty sure the definition of newTeam is fine, and in fact, I can see the results in the DOM and it's fine, and works if I copy and paste it into the static HTML page. Simply doesn't work when dynamically generated.

Answer (score 2):

Some browsers (like IE) do not respond well when you append elements to the DOM as strings (specially with forms, i've had issues appending options to a select element i.e), I suggest trying to append it as a jquery object instead:

```
var teamName = "Dansk";
var newTeam = $("<input />", {type: 'hidden', name: 'tag', value: teamName});
$('#team-display').append(newTeam);
```

Also make sure that you are appending the input inside the form.

Comment: This unfortunately does not work for me. I am using Chrome btw. And I am definitely adding the element inside the form, and if I view the dynamically-generated input in Chrome's inspector, then paste it into the static HTML form in the exact same place, THEN it works. But not when created dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

Well I solved this - I had my FORM opening tag in a certain spot, but then the /FORM tag was not at the same level - it was inside a DIV a bit later on. The weird thing is that despite this, the extra input (and the rest of the form) worked if it was hard-coded into the HTML, but the exact same extra input did not work when dynamically generated by jQuery

Comment: So @Paul had it right!

Answer (score 0):

Did you copy/paste that js exactly?

[image]

```
var newTeam = "<input type="hidden" name="tag" value="' + teamName + '">";
```

Should be...

(if you insist on keeping the double quotes in the rendered HTML)

```
var newTeam = "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"tag\" value=\"" + teamName + "\">"; 
// could have ended it with '">' as a fix also, just stuck with double quotes for consistency
```